# Javascript - using null as default parameter

Tags: javascript

I started using null as a default for optional function parameters. (obviously unless something else is more appropriate)

It seemed to make sense - (from ECMA spec) "null value - 
primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value" and when reading the function for the first time it makes it immediately clear the parameter is optional.

A hard-core, dyed in the wool JS guy at my work HATES it, but when I push him, his reasons are all a bit... Undefined (!)

I know it's mostly falsy checks anyway but can anyone give me a good RATIONAL reason for not doing this?

**Eloboration following initial comments**

Imagine a function like this

```
complicatedFunc(arg 1, arg2, arg3, arg4) {

long func

}
```

As it stands it doesn't tell a second user anything about what arguments are required/optional.

Same function

```
const complicatedFunc = (arg 1, arg2, arg3 = null, arg4 = null) => {

long func...

}
```

ie the docs (which are never written) would be

complicatedFunc(arg1, arg2, [arg3, arg4])....

It seems obvious that the second version is clearer and would be less likely to be used wrongly

As as I said above, you would only use null if another default wasn't more appropriate.

I can think of good pros, but not really any cons?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Might be a question better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Depends entirely on how you use your functions. For example, if instead of separate getter and setter functions you just use one function with an optional argument (which is rare, but not unheard of), e.g. `obj.someProperty()` to get and `obj.someProperty(someValue)` to set, then calling `obj.someProperty(null)` and interpreting `null` as the "intentional absence" of a value can mean the method will be invoked as a getter, instead of setting the property to `null`.

Comment: In the absence of a parameter, its default value is `undefined`. Can you first elaborate why you overload it with `null`? A piece of sample code could make your point clearer.

Comment: @Tyler when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @MátéSafranka for getter and setter function you should use  `argument.length` to determine if the function is called with one or zero aruments.

Comment: `undefined` is defined as `primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value`, so if a parameter is optional, then `undefined` is the correct state, because then no value is assigned. With `null` you say I don't want to have an object/value at that place. It is a semantically difference. You for sure can argue about that, but (imho) all major libraries interpret it that way, so you will make your and the life of the other developer easier if you stay with the common practice.

Comment: All fair points but what your saying is we all do it that way and so even if slightly irrational (ie current use makes no explicit separation between intentionally and unintentionally absent) we should keep doing the same. (and the truth is, I will!) If JS was changed so that undefined function args threw an error (like Python) imho that could only be an improvement